# how to create a hidden watermark for images to survive (at least) resizing

Tags: php, image, algorithm, watermark

i am going to create my own (hidden) watermark for my images at my homepage. The idea is to sign each image on the fly per user.

the vision is to be able to tell from which user the image was leaked when finding it somewhere else.

i was going to use alpha pixel to "sign" the img when asking myself "how do my watermark will survive resizing?"

i have no idea and would be glad if you could point me to best practices / algorithms / ideas.

thx for your time and help

EDIT
to elaborate about my watermark idea. I was going to take an unique identifier for the user (name / hash /id) and map into hopefully unique x/y coordinate and paint them over the existing image. Ofcourse this have to work also in reverse where i map the alpha pixels back into the uniqe user identifier. But i cant work with x/y coordinates when i want to take resizing into account, can i?

Comment: Digital watermarking is a non-trivial issue. You need to start consulting literature e.g. http://www.eurecom.fr/fr/publication/975/detail/a-survey-of-watermarking-algorithms-for-image-authentication.

Comment: also found this https://github.com/mchall/HiddenWatermark

Answer (score 0):

You can try use Steganography.

Or just save same information in JPG service fields. For example in EXIF.